# Buying US iTunes card from UK

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I have a US iTunes account and a friend - also from the US but currently in the UK - wants to send me an iTunes gift card.

My question is: can he buy this card valid for the US Store with his US credit card but from his UK location. Is this possible?

And will it be sent to me digitally as I am also not in the US right now.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's correct. Otherwise ask for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that would be possible. You don’t have to be in the same country as your account is for.

You just can’t use an American dollar voucher on an English account as they use pounds.

Answer (score 0):

No UK cards are valid for UK accounts, it won't work on US account. Your friend can use [PCGameSupply](http://www.pcgamesupply.com); it's what I use for my US account when I'm not in US. You can buy cards for almost any country, and it's digitally delivered.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear - I meant he is in the UK but he has a US iTunes account with US card. I meant can he use it though he is in the UK? It's not geo-restricted?

Comment: @alkaemia Oh yeah. He can do that. I do it all the time. I use my US account all the time, when I'm not in US.